# Flutter SQFlite Populate List from DB records

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have the following class:

```
final String itemTable = 'myItemsTable';

class itemFields {
  static final List<String> values = [id, myText];
  static final String id = '_id';
  static final String myText = 'myText';
}

class Item {
  late final int? id;
  late String? myText = '';
  Item({required this.id,required this.myText,});
  Item copy({int? id, String? myText}) => Item(id: id ?? this.id,myText: myText ?? this.myText,);
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
    if (id != null) itemFields.id: id,itemFields.myText: myText,};
  static Item fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => Item(id: json[visibleCursorFields.id] as int?,myText: myText(json[item.myText].toString()),);
}
```

now, I define the list:

```
static late List<Item> items = <Item>[];
```

Here, I want to populate data from the database:

```
Future<List<Item>> getAllItems() async {
    return await MyFormState.items;
}
```

Issue: I don't understand how to properly populate data. The above code is not working.

I will be using FutureBuilder, and I need to use getAllItems().

Here, I physically extract data from the database:

```
Future<List<Item>> readAllItems() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $Table');
    final list = result.map((json) => Item.fromJson(json)).toList();
    if(list.isNotEmpty) return list; else throw Exception('Empty List');
  }
```

This is the list that I need to populate from the database:

```
Widget mylist = SizedBox(width: 800, height: 500, child: FutureBuilder<List<Item>?>(builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Item>?> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState!=null && snapshot.connectionState== ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text('Test is loading'));
      }
      return ListView.separated(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),shrinkWrap: true,itemCount: getAllItems(),itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(height: 60,child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: <Widget>[
          Text(MyFormState.items[index].txt,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
        ],
        )));
      },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider());
    }, future: getAllItems()
    ));
```

Could you please provide any suggestions.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `snapshot.data!` which is `List<Item>`, that `readAllItems()` is returning.
2. For listView item, count use the `snapshot.data!`'s size.
3. If you're reading data from `readAllItems()`, why are you using `MyFormState.items[index].txt`

Here is your refactored code:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: readAllItems(), //future method
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text("Something went wrong");
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Item> items = snapshot.data!; //snapshot.data is List<Item> returned from future method
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length, //data's size
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  child: Text(items[index].myTxt),//using items data
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const Text('No data available');
          }
        },
      )
```

Comment: I am using MyFormState.items[index].txt to populate the UI list from the database. I revised the code for List, but I am having trouble with this code: Future<List<Item>> readAllItems() async {return await MyFormState.items;}. This code does not extract anything from the SQFLite database. Hence, I changed this code to:  Future<List<Item>> readtAllItems() async {return MyFormState.items = await DBHelper.instance.readAllItems();;}. This code keeps updating the UI, but the list is never shown. Please help. Thank You

Comment: Future<List<Item>> getAllItems() async {
    return await DBHelper.instance.readAllItems();
}

try this

Comment: Question: if I don't have any data in the database, then I see the message on the entire screen: "Something went wrong". How do I change the code to show the UI with empty data and do not show the above message? Thank You